# How do I find leak from second floor shower. Shower is located in room by itself so it's definitely from it

Tags: plumbing, shower, ceiling, leak, drain

My second floor shower leaks when my husband leans against wall and slides down to sit in shower. If he just stands in shower, it doesn't seem to leak. The ceiling below room is already removed to expose pipes but I can't see leak from the pipes. How would I check if it's the drain that's causing the leak?

Comment: Do you know how the walls are constructed? I'm wondering if the one he leans on is flexing enough to open a crack in the sealant along one edge. BTW when I had to sit in the shower after an injury, I had a plastic garden chair in there (but getting up from the floor would have been a problem)

Comment: What's the condition of the caulk at the sides and bottom of the wall?  There *is* caulk there, right?  Tile wall?  Composite surround?

Comment: Depends on the exact geometry involved. Drying things out and then strategically attaching dry paper towels can be helpful. False positives are possible because of water running down from above, though.

Comment: A well-lit and focused photo of the open ceiling showing where you see the leak coming through would help as would a photo of the shower floor.  If the leak is so fast and in such volume that you can easily associate it with a brief action like sitting down, it should be easy-ish= to find the location, and maybe the cause of the problem just by looking.  If he has balance or similar issues, you could have him sit beneath the open ceiling filming video while you experiment with leaning and pushing in various ways, and have him speak on the video what actions you're taking.

Answer (score 0):

If it leaks only when he leans against the wall, then it is unlikely to be a pipe.

Get him to lean and sit down, while you are downstairs looking for the leak.

Its possibly the main shower drain or the walls themselves.

Comment: Shower wall, or built-in-seat, waterproofing failure will not necessarily be observable from below, will likely require demolishment and rebuild of shower structure to a higher standard. Water-tightness of a properly built shower will in no way rely on caulk or grout joints, which are cosmetic only.

Comment: @kreemoweet maybe!  Or maybe it's just a washer that's cracked or screwed too tight in the drain line, and leaning flexes it a bit.   Optimistic but possible.